# Connecting a new Android project with parse-server-example and parse-dashboard (local)

Tags: android, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I am trying to connect a new android project with the parse-server-example (locally) and showing it with the parse-dashboard. I have successfully linked parse-server-example with parse-dashboard...(by changing appId and masterKey in parse-server-example/index.js and in parse-dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json). I have installed mongodb and everything (mongodb,parse-server-example and parse-dashboard is working perfectly).

But now when i am trying to initialize parse server in android project, it does not create anything(class) in parse locally.(working fine with parse.com). Thanks. MY code

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright (c) 2015-present, Parse, LLC.
  ~ All rights reserved.
  ~
  ~ This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
  ~ LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
  ~ of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
  -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parse.starter" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".StarterApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build.gradle file

```
...

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseObject;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());


  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

StarterApplication.java

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Application;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;


public class StarterApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
   //Parse.initialize(this);

      Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
              .applicationId("@string/parse_app_id")
              .clientKey("@string/parse_client_key")
              .server("http://localhost:1337/parse/")   // '/' important after 'parse'
              .build());

      ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
      testObject.put("foo", "bar");
      testObject.saveInBackground();


      ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
  }
}
```

I have also tried putting the creation of object in main activtiy

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground();

  }
```

Comment: make sure you delete the following lines in you Android Manifest file <meta-data android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="@string/parse_app_id" /> <meta-data android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY" android:value="@string/parse_client_key" /> this is because since you are using a custom config in your Starter Application.java

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have localhost in your code? Localhost means that the request is running on local device, you can use it inside server but not on a client device. Try to put there some IP address of the server/your computer

```
.server("http://localhost:1337/parse/")
```

Comment: Thank you..for the answer..Solved it !!

Comment: And what did u do for ParseUser.getCurrentUser(). Documentation says use request.user but then what is request object.

Comment: instead of localhost write the IP address of the server that the remote device can access remotly, for example 10.0.0.3 or 192.168.1.1, your IP address will look differently

Answer (score 0):

In your initialize method, use .server(API_ADDRESS) , the api address is provided by the parse service provider. e.g. back4app call it API Address