# Localhost parse integration with android simulator

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-emulator, parse-server

I am trying to setup parse server on my localhost and trying to connect to my app simulator.

Here is my code of parse

```
// Example express application adding the parse-server module to expose Parse
// compatible API routes.

var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI;

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://abc:27017/parse',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'chat-test',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'chat-test', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  facebookAppIds: 'abc' //FaceBook App ID Keys. Comma Separated.
});
// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey

var app = express();

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('I dream of being a web site.');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

I am using

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getBaseContext()).applicationId("chat-test").server("http:/localhost:1337/parse/").build());
```

i got this all from live server and just replaced to localhost, but i cna't make the android connect to localhost. it gives me i/o failure.

How can i make my android simulator work with this localhost parse

Comment: What gives you i/o failure? What is your exact error or logcat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Android simulator is actually a virtual machine which means that localhost is an internal IP to the simulator. You can access your computer via the ip `10.0.2.2`.

This means you should change the URL to `http://10.0.2.2:1337/parse/`.

The full line of code should be:

```java
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getBaseContext()).applicationId("chat-test").server("http://10.0.2.2:1337/parse/").build());
```

This is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have localhost in your code? Localhost means that the request is running on local device, you can use it inside server but not on a client device. Try to put there some IP address of the server/your computer, it was also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975760/connecting-a-new-android-project-with-parse-server-example-and-parse-dashboard/35984612#35984612)

```
.server("http://localhost:1337/parse/")
```